# MC3074 - type does not exist in "clr-namespace..."

Tags: wpf, data-binding, reference

Im having trouble referencing classes in xaml from other assemblies.

In the same solution, i have two projects. One called Controls (to hold user controls) and one called DataBinding (holding converters / validation rules). In a control, im attempting reference a validation rule in xaml:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
   <databind:Validators.FileExistsRule />
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

My project references the project containing my classes. Ive added this declaration at the top of my Control.xaml:

```
xmlns:databind="clr-namespace:GuiParts.DataBinding;assembly=DataBinding"
```

However, when i compile, i get an error:

```
The tag 'Validators.FileExistsRule' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:GuiParts.DataBinding;assembly=DataBinding'.
```

The class definitely exists, i can call it in the code behind with no problems, but not via xaml. If i move the class to the same project, again, i have no problems. Ive seen other questions on here, and have tried the following:

1. Cleaning and rebuilding all relevant projects
2. Ensuring all projects are targeting the same version of .Net (4.0, Full Profile)
3. Removing the 'assembly' definition from the end of the namespace definition.

None of the above has worked. Any suggestions as to where im going wrong?

EDIT

My FileExists Validator:

```
namespace GuiParts.DataBinding.Validators
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Validates that the file with the specified name exists
   /// </summary>
   public class FileExistsRule : ValidationRule
   {
      public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
      {
         ValidationResult res = null;
         res = ( ! File.Exists((string)value))
                  ? new ValidationResult(false, "File does not exist")
                  : new ValidationResult(true, null);
         return res;
      }
   }
}
```

I can call the following in the code behind without any errors:

```
new GuiParts.DataBinding.Validators.FileExistsRule();
```

So ive got my namespaces etc. correct.

Comment: You're method can be a 1 line statement: `return File.Exists((string)value) ? new ValidationResult(false, "File does not exist.") : new ValidationResult(true, null);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
xmlns:databind="clr-namespace:GuiParts.DataBinding.Validators;assembly=DataBinding"

<Binding.ValidationRules>    
    <databind:FileExistsRule />    
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

Comment: +1 This helped me out, I needed to specify the assembly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Is your class in your target assembly public?
2. Is the field in Validators, public?
3. Is your namespace GuiParts.DataBinding correct?

Comment: Edited question with more detail

Comment: These questions were necessary at the time because the question had so little detail this was the only advice one could provide. Please consider that when voting.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not sure what the issue you're having is, you can alternatively create a friendlier namespace definition for your assembly and CLR namespaces. In fact, I use this technique to group various namespaces into one XML namespace... You do this using the [`XmlnsPrefixAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsprefixattribute) and the [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx)s.

For example:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://my.xml.namespace.com/", "databind")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://my.xml.namespace.com/",
    "GuiParts.DataBinding")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://my.xml.namespace.com/",
    "GuiParts.DataBinding.Validators")]
```

Then, when you want to reference the xmlnamespace in your xaml you simply do:

```
xmlns:databind="http://my.xml.namespace.com/"
```

---

Note, I use ReSharper, but I'm sure this also works naturally in Visual Studio. If you don't type in the xmlns import and attempt to use an object in the namespace, then when you go to resolve it it will automatically use the friendlier named namespace with the specified prefix. Also, it's really nice and helps you avoid having a 1:1 relationship between xml namespaces and clr namespaces because you can map multiple clr namespaces into a single xml namespace.

Again, I'm not sure what the issue you're having specifically is, but this will probably fix it and be better than using clr-namespaces and assembly information. Just make sure to come up with something unique so you don't run into xmlns collisions or you'll have to go back to clr/assembly namespacing.

---

Oh, and one last thing... if you wish to utilize versioning in your xml namespace naming scheme (which you should), don't worry about locking yourself in for backwards compatibility. You can always utilize the [`XmlnsCompatibleWithAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnscompatiblewithattribute) to ensure that code that utilized the old friendly namespace doesn't break if you ever update your external assemblies to map to a newer xml namespace.

For example, if you originally had you're assembly pointing to a 2012 namespace, then switched it to a 2013 namespace because you updated the assembly...

```
// Previous Assembly version
//[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.xyzcorp.com/wpf/2012",
//    "Xyz.Databinding")]

[assembly: XmlnsCompatibleWith("http://schemas.xyzcorp.com/wpf/2012",
    "http://schemas.xyzcorp.com/wpf/2013")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.xyzcorp.com/wpf/2013",
     "Xyz.Databinding")]
```